# Penalty method and the question of equivalence in a specific optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I encountered an interesting problem in “Practical Methods of Optimization” by R. Fletcher, which utilizes the penalty method to solve the following  constrained optimization problem
\begin{align}
{\mathop{\text{minimize} }} \quad &  \left \| Ay \right \|^2   \\ 
 \text{s}\text{.t}\text{.}  \quad\quad\quad\,\,&
y \ge 0 \, , \,\, e^Ty = 1.
\end{align}

The solution $y^*$ of this problem can be obtained by solving the problem
\begin{align}
{\mathop{\text{minimize} }} \quad &  \left \| Ay \right \|^2 + \left ( e^Ty - 1 \right ) ^2  \\ 
 \text{s}\text{.t}\text{.}  \quad\quad\quad\,\,&
y \ge 0
\end{align}

giving a vector $y'$ say, and normalizing to get $y^* = y'/(e^Ty')$.

My question is that why is the equivalence true? While the normalization makes sense intuitively, why should it yield the answer to the original problem?
I tried writing the KKT conditions for both problems and it seems the equivalence can be derived, but with a lot of manipulation. Is there a simpler way to justify the equivalence?

Comment: I don't see a lot of manipulation in their KKTs